# AWS CloudWatch Agent failing because it is detecting himself as On-Premise

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm running an EC2 with Amazon Linux 2 On which I have installed AWS Cloud Watch Agent
After configuring it with the following:

```
{
  "agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "run_as_user": "cwagent"
  },
  "metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
      "disk": {
        "measurement": [
          "used_percent"
        ],
        "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
        "resources": [
          "/"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have ran
`tail -f /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log`
to make sure the configuration is working,But I have received the following errors:

```
I! Detected the instance is OnPremise
2023/06/21 11:52:36 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
2023/06/21 11:52:36 I! Valid Json input schema.
I! Detecting run_as_user...
2023/06/21 11:52:36 E! Credentials path is not set while runasuser is not root
2023/06/21 11:52:36 E! Credentials path is not set while runasuser is not root
2023/06/21 11:52:36 Configuration validation first phase failed. Agent version: 1.0. Verify the JSON input is only using features supported by this version.

2023/06/21 11:52:36 I! Return exit error: exit code=1
2023/06/21 11:52:36 E! Cannot translate JSON config into TOML, ERROR is exit status 1
```

I have Installed and configured the CW Agent according to:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html
I have made sure network connectivity is working.
I have tried to reinstall the Agent, thinking I have might have screwed up something during installation, But none of the above have fixed it.

---

Based on comments here are more test results:
I have ensured I have the latest version of CloudWatch Running + I have checked my FW.
the log file  `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log` shows as below:

```
2023/07/05 07:59:41 I! D! [EC2] Found active network interface
E! ec2metadata is not available
I! Detected the instance is OnPremise
2023/07/05 07:59:41 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json ...
2023/07/05 07:59:41 E! Failed to generate merged json config: unable to get old json config file with error: unable to parse json, error: invalid character '}' after top-level value
2023/07/05 07:59:41 E! Failed to generate merged json config: unable to get old json config file with error: unable to parse json, error: invalid character '}' after top-level value
2023/07/05 07:59:41 Configuration validation first phase failed. Agent version: 1.0. Verify the JSON input is only using features supported by this version.

2023/07/05 07:59:41 I! Return exit error: exit code=1
2023/07/05 07:59:41 E! Cannot translate JSON config into TOML, ERROR is exit status 1
```

I have tested the connection to the meta data service using
`wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id && echo`

and received the instance id in the output

Comment: Do you have the EC2 instance metadata feature disabled? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/configuring-instance-metadata-options.html

Comment: I have checked the feature is enabled,

Answer (score 2):

If you want the CloudWatch agent to run as a non-root user, you must properly configure sudoers. In your case, you want the CloudWatch agent to run as `cwagent`. You can try to update your sudoers file (usually located at /etc/sudoers) with something like this:

```
cwagent ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

This line allows the `cwagent` user to run sudo commands without a password, effectively granting it the necessary permissions.

Alternatively, you can run the CloudWatch agent as the root user. Change the "run_as_user": "cwagent" line in your configuration to "run_as_user": "root".

Additionally, you might want to check if the version of the CloudWatch agent you're using supports all the features you're trying to use.

Remember to restart the CloudWatch agent after making these changes as follows:

```
sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -s -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
```

===

!Update based on your comment!

Here are a couple of things you can try:

Ensure that you have the latest version of the CloudWatch agent installed:

```
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -v
```

If it's not the latest version, update it.

Use the `amazon-cloudwatch-agent-config-wizard` to create a new configuration file and see if that helps.
Once you have the new configuration file, try applying it again.

Check your firewall rules to ensure that outbound connections to 169.254.169.254 on port 80 are allowed.

Review the agent logs at `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log` to see if there's additional information about why it's failing to access the metadata service.

Ensure the EC2 instance has an IAM role with sufficient permissions to interact with CloudWatch.

Comment: I have tried and run it as root but when running the command I receive the following. 
` Trying to detect region from ec2
D! [EC2] Found active network interface
E! ec2metadata is not available
I! Trying to detect region from ecs
Unable to determine aws-region.
E! Please check if you can access the metadata service. For example, on linux, run wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id && echo
Fail to fetch the config!` 
when checking if I can access the metadata server as suggested by the error, I'm able to access it

Comment: I have added additional things to try based on your comment.

Comment: I have updated my post based on your comment with the new results, still no luck